# Installing Windows 7 games on Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-8

I wish to play all of the games that I have on Windows 7 by default (chess, freecell, minesweeper, etc) on my Windows 8 machine.

I tried to just copy over the relevant .exe files, but when I run them (even in Windows 7 compatibility mode) nothing happens (no errors, no running process, nothing).

How can I get my games working?

**Note:** I tried the [Into Windows Guide: How To Play Windows 7 Games In Windows 8](http://www.intowindows.com/play-windows-7-games-in-windows-8/) and after I downloaded the patch, it still did not work.

Comment: Do you have an nVidia graphics card?

Comment: @RandolphWest Yup. Up to date drivers, 260M

Comment: I cannot run any Metro apps with my 560M nVidia, and the behaviour sounds the same. No error, no running process, nothing. I believe there's a known issue with nVidia cards. **EDIT** I cannot run Windows 7 games on my 8 install either.

Comment: @RandolphWest I have no problems with the built in metro apps, or others that I download. Additionally, these games came from win 7 and so are not metro.

Comment: Well I can't exclude nVidia being a problem on my machine, but the 7 games definitely do not start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that the files were in the wrong folder, and where therefore calling the x86 versions of the api, when they should have been calling the x64 versions.

Just moving them into the `Program Files` folder (as opposed to the `Program Files (x86)` folder) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Try to start FreeCell under [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

1. File -> Open -> `FreeCell.exe`
2. Profile -> Start profiling

Of course, you  **must** use appropriate (x32/x64) version of Depends, otherwise you'll get error "Modules with different CPU types were found".

After process `FreeCell.exe` exits search the log for red lines. May be they give the clue. Incorrect paths for example...

Comment: Useful program. Copied in a .dll file, but then I a bunch of problems with the win api (API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL).

Comment: Are you sure, executable was successfully patched? Just tried patch 1.2 on my tablet (Win8 customer preview **x86**) and it works, running from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\FreeCell\FreeCell.exe`

Comment: Thats what it said at the end (had to manually find all the .exe files though)