# Windows 7: programs installed to AppData won't launch

Tags: windows-7, process

I don't know what causes it, but after a while, all programs installed to the AppData will stop launching. as far as I can see, they doesn't show up in Task Manager's processes tab at all after I open them. they just won't open.

like I said, this only happens after a few hours of using Windows, the programs launch fine after first booting. the only way I can seem to fix it is to reboot, but that's only temporary.

and some apps don't support being installed for all users in Program Files, so that's not an option.

Windows 7 x64 SP1

Comment: Try to run under Depends: http://superuser.com/a/455103/139371

Comment: okay, it gave me this error message: "Error: Modules with different CPU types were found. Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."

Comment: I believe, there is more information. Search for incorrect modules. May be %PATH% envvar variable relate this problem. Or some program (virus :-P) change your system files.

Comment: Another thought: note about "cpu types" lead to conclusion, that your program fail to load some dlls with correct bit-type (x32/x64). Search for the problem in log.

Comment: it shows all the DLL files as x64, whereas the program I am trying to launch (Google Chrome) is x86. I have a 64-bit computer, but is this the problem? also: "Profile > Start Profiling..." is greyed out, so I haven't been able to try that.

Comment: You may also run Process Monitor. May be it log (accessed file paths) give you a clue

Comment: I tried that, and it showed SHARING VIOLATION for the file %LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\unpacker.exe. I went to the file and it showed the icon of Google Chrome. after deleting the file and trying another application, both the application and Google Chrome launch correctly! it also recreated the unpacker.exe file, although this time with the icon of the second program. why is this this problem?

Comment: Not sure, many possible cases. (anti)virus blocking acces, some app/tool modified the file, or anything else... Btw, you owe to use Depends x86 (32bit) to profile x86 application, of course

Comment: well thanks for helping me identify the issue, I think I know how to sort through it from here.